# setExpressCheckout failing when I add parameters to returnURL

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, returnurl

I have a working (in the Sandbox) ExpressCheckout payment flow.  I am attempting to add a parameter to the ReturnURL argument in the SetExpressCheckout call.  As soon as I add a parameter the call fails with an error of invalid ReturnURL.

I've tried different parameter names, and always get the same error.  If I remove all parameters it works fine.

Code that works:
  RETURNURL = 'http://mywebaddress.com'

Code that causes error:
  RETURNURL = 'http://mywebaddress.com?transid=123'

To add a little more detail, here is the error returned by paypal:

"TIMESTAMP":"2014-05-29T23:58:20Z",
"CORRELATIONID":"3313de9c9e0cc",
"ACK":"Failure",
"VERSION":"111.0",
"BUILD":"11196751",
"L_ERRORCODE0":"10471",
"L_SHORTMESSAGE0":"Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.",
"L_LONGMESSAGE0":"ReturnURL is invalid.",
"L_SEVERITYCODE0":"Error"

Comment: Is there more information you can provide about the error (for example, the full trace and/or error message)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your url encoding in the failing url. I think it might work like this: 'http://mywebaddress.com%2ftransid=123' (deleted ? and added correct url encoding for forward slash '%2f')

Comment: Adding a "/" between the hostname and the "?" seems to have done the trick.  Thanks.